# UIPageViewController: Are methods of the delegate are called in response to gesture-based navigation and orientation changes only

Tags: iphone, ipad

I go through the `UIPageViewController` reference and found this statement.

> Methods of the delegate are called in response to gesture-based
>   navigation and orientation       changes.

same for datasource. Does it means that `UIPageViewController` delegate is called by gesture only, we can not call it by buttons actions. Has anybody faced such situation before.

Answer (score 0):

Data source is called everytime the controller needs to get a new page which you can re-create or reuse ... it should only store pages that are visible or might be visible after a user touches the device.

With delegates, I am not sure but I think they will be called only if the action is invoked by a gesture or orientation as I can't see any point of telling you that you changed the page when this is invoked by the code itself ... theory only!